# Convert python x509 Signing Request object (x509.CertificateSigningRequest) object to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, encryption

I need to convert an x509.CertificateSigningRequest object to bytes

Here is the method that returns the x509.CertificateSigningRequest object

```py
def csr(private_key: rsa.RSAPrivateKey) -> x509.CertificateSigningRequest:
    b = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder()
    req = b.subject_name(x509.Name([
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"CA"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"San Francisco"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"Command1"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"Commandment"),
    ])).sign(private_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

    return req
```

Does someone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just doing

> req_bytes=req.public_bytes(encoding=serializaion.Encoding.PEM)

will solve the issue